# What object characteristics may cause significant distance measurement deviations in Sharp optical sensors?

Tags: sensors, distance-measurement

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but anyways. I'm not very fond of circuits and stuff, but I've got a test question I really need to answer. The question is in the title, possible answer options are:

- Fibrous surface
- Temperature
- Thermal conductivity
- Velocity
- Opacity
- Average density
- Color
- Electromagnetic radio waves radiation (as far as I understand, the question suggests that we're speaking about waves produced by the object that we are measuring distance to itself)

Multiple choices are possible. I didn't manage to find an answer on the internet, so I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: all of them depending what you are trying to measure...

Comment: @SolarMike, apparently, I'm measuring distance to an object with an infrared Sharp sensor. And the deviations must be significant. Does this add more certainty?